# Downloading Multiple Files from SkyDrive with Live 5.3

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive, windows-phone-8-emulator, live-sdk, windows-phone-7.8

I'm trying to download one or more files from SkyDrive using the Windows Phone emulator. I'm pretty new at the Live SDK and I'm lost following these pages:

[multiple file download using SkyDrive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336362/multiple-file-download-using-skydrive-api)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#downloading_files

They both use methods and classes not provided in Live SDK 5.3 (more specifically, client.DownloadCompleted and LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using Windows Phone 8.0 SDK. `DownloadCompleted` and `LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs` are part of the `Microsoft.Live` namespace on WP7.1.

In Windows Phone 8.0 `DownloadAsync()` is used with the `await` keyword. You can use it with or without progress notification.

Sample:

```cs
var result = await client.DownloadAsync(path); // path will be file id followed by '/content'
var stream = result.Stream;
```